# ESP8266 - CIPSEND & external power supply Hangs program

Tags: serial, esp8266

**Updated**:

I connected my esp to external power, the blue light stays on, I start getting garbage data. 
I used voltage regulator which was giving 3.4v, power supply tested with 1A &  2A.

**Old problem :**

I have been trying to make ESP8266 since my last semester exams & now 2nd semester exams are going on. So i've been trying to make ESP8266 work for very long time. 
Earlier it was firmware problem, i updated it.

After a lot it worked. I tried many libraries - but none worked, either some are using specific port or some want specific firmware version which is really hard to find & then flash.

I am using telnet to check. 
When i disable code to send data - i can send data madly, it works & never hangs up. But as i use `AT+CPISEND` after 1-2 read/write - it stops responding.

I am powering using arduino with/out voltage divider. Its firmware - `0020000903`, `AT Firmware v1.5`, 4mb flash size, I changed baudrate to `9600`.

Below is code i worte : 
( I intentionally didn't remove comments)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.
#define DEBUG true

SoftwareSerial esp8266(9,10); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
                             // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
                             // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
void setup()
{

  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);

  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);

  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);


  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600); // your esp's baud rate might be different

Serial.print("Sending at..");
  sendData("AT",2000,DEBUG);
  //sendData("AT+RST",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=1",1000,DEBUG);
 // sendData("AT+CWLAP",1000,DEBUG);
 //sendData("AT+CIOBAUD=9600",1000,DEBUG);
 //sendData("AT+UART=9600,8,1,0,0",1000,DEBUG);
 //sendData("AT+IPR=9600",1000,DEBUG);
 // sendData("AT+CWJAP_DEF=\"mad\",\"agentis47?orBond?\"",15000,DEBUG);
 //sendData("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure as access point
  sendData("AT+CIFSR",1000,DEBUG); // get ip address
  sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1",1000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
  sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80
}

void loop()
{

  if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {

    while(esp8266.available())
    {
      // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
      char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
      Serial.write(c);
    } 

    //Serial.println("IPD Search "+(len));
    if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
    {

     delay(20); // wait for the serial buffer to fill up (read all the serial data)
     // get the connection id so that we can then disconnect
     int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns 
                                           // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48

     esp8266.read(); //skip the comma ','
     //(CIPMUX=0): + IPD, <len>:
     //(CIPMUX=1): + IPD, <id>, <len>: <data>
     int len = (readUntil(":")).toInt();
     if(len>500) len = 500; //prevent extra data we won't be sending more than 500bytes in one go. 
     char data[len];

     esp8266.readBytes(data, len);
     //data[len-2]='\0';


      int pinNumber = (data[0]-48)*10; // get first number i.e. if the pin 13 then the 1st number is 1, then multiply to get 10
     pinNumber += ((data[1])-48); // get second number, i.e. if the pin number is 13 then the 2nd number is 3, then add to the first number

       digitalWrite(pinNumber, !digitalRead(pinNumber)); 
    Serial.println(String(len));

     /*Serial.println("===");

     Serial.println("--");
*/
    //cleanBuffer();
    //delay(10);
     //Serial.println("Sendddiddding data");
     //sendData(connectionId,String("OK"));
     //Serial.println("Sent");     
     //closeConnection(connectionId);


     //digitalWrite(pinNumber, !digitalRead(pinNumber)); // toggle pin    

     // make close command
     //String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
     //closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id
     //closeCommand+="\r\n";

     //sendData(closeCommand,1000,DEBUG); // close connection
    }
  }
}

void cleanBuffer(){
  while(esp8266.available())
    {
      // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
      char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
      Serial.write(c);
    }
}

String sendData(int connectionId, String data){
  //Serial.println("AT+CIPSEND="+String(connectionId)+ ","+String(data.length()));
  //sendData("AT+CIPSEND="+String(connectionId)+ ","+String(data.length()),1000,DEBUG);
  //sendData(data,100,DEBUG);
  //closeConnection(connectionId);
  String webpage = "<h1>Hello</h1>&lth2>World!</h2><button>LED1</button>";

     String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
     cipSend += connectionId;
     cipSend += ",";
     cipSend +=webpage.length();
     cipSend +="\r\n";

     sendData(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
     sendData(webpage,1000,DEBUG);

     webpage="<button>LED2</button>";

     cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
     cipSend += connectionId;
     cipSend += ",";
     cipSend +=webpage.length();


     sendData(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
     sendData(webpage,1000,DEBUG);

     String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
     closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id


     sendData(closeCommand,3000,DEBUG);

 /*
  Serial.println("finding prompt");
  if(esp8266.find(">"))    //prompt offered by esp8266
  {
    Serial.println("Sending data");
   // Serial.println("found > prompt - issuing GET request");  //a debug message
    esp8266.println(data);  //this is our http GET request
  }
  else
  {
    closeConnection(connectionId);
    Serial.println("No '>' prompt received after AT+CPISEND");
  }
*/
}

String closeConnection(int connectionId){
    sendData("AT+CIPCLOSE="+String(connectionId),100,DEBUG);
}

String readUntil(String delimiter){
  String response = "";  
  char c; 
  unsigned int dLen = delimiter.length(),n=0;

    while(esp8266.available()&&(c= esp8266.read())){
      n= (c==delimiter[n])?n+1:0;
      if(n==dLen) break; 
      response+=c;
    }
   return response;
}

void sendRaw(String data){
esp8266.print(data);
}

String sendCommand(String command){
  esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266
  esp8266.print("\r\n");
  esp8266.flush();
}

String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";
    esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266
    esp8266.print("\r\n");
    esp8266.flush();
    long int time = millis();

    do
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }while( (time+timeout) > millis());
    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }    
    return response;
}
```

Please help, I am stuck, Is there any other cheaper & better solution ? I am only looking for Wifi.

Answer (score 1):

If you are powering it using Arduino 3.3V pin it is no wonder it does not work. 
ESP8266 uses more power than Arduino can provide. Power pin on arduino is about 50ma. ESP8266 in receive or send mode uses much more and either halts or restarts.

[A table of ESP8266 power consumption can be found here](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=133)

Comment: can you suggest power regulator which is easily available ?

Comment: any Buck Step Down Converter. There is literally gazillion of them on ebay and on... Use it to step down 5V that you get from any phone charger to 3.3V. You could also use something like [this for use with breadboard](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-Board-MB102-Breadboard-Power-Supply-Module-3-3V-5V-For-Arduino-/171907055454?hash=item2806757f5e:g:iWAAAOxy1RZSY9yF)

Comment: @m11404 you can easily buy a cheap 3.3V linear regulator LM1117T and use it with the Arduino 5V pin, which can supply up to 500mA; a separate 1A supply would be even better.

Comment: I already had that... I used 5v,1A adapter... &  connected esp without voltage divider... The led in esp was dim... &  not responding

Comment: I am getting yyyyyyyyy.... Similar as response if I connect external power.

Comment: make sure that your terminal baud speed is set correct. go from 9600 and up. See if that fixes it. And put the capacitor between vcc and ground.

Comment: Wait ? You connected the ESP to 5V without the voltage divider? ESP is 3.3V. You fried your ESP module.

Comment: @NccWarp9 Hey, No...Its not fried, i used voltage regulator. I also tried using 3A DC-DC Converter Step Down buck http://www.ebay.in/itm/Supper-mini-3A-DC-DC-Converter-Step-Down-buck-Power-Supply-Module-3V-5V-16V-/331854215553?hash=item4d440d7981:g:1ywAAOSwt7pXNFQz

ESP echoes back whatever i type. No error.

& it works fine if i correct directly to uno.

Baud rate is 9600 as i changed it using AT, Should i reflash & use 115200 with external power ?

Comment: I will try a 100uf capacitor.

I also monitored current  - while connected to uno it was fluctuating from 70mA to 30mA..i  don't remember exactly but there was lot of fluctuations but when i connect to external no fluctuation  , blue blinks once, red light is OK.   this is result when i connect to external power & directly to serial. 

The source is rated to 2A, 5V.

Comment: If i use arduino promini with esp, it keeps resetting i believe because of less power.  & once it worked but there was lots of garbage text. & then it started resetting. 

I am really thankful to you.  Thank you for replying. I didn't get notification for your comment so this was late reply.

Comment: older modules come with only 9600 and to get it to work with higher baud rates you will need to flash it with newer firmware. did you flash it with 0.9v of the firmware that has baud watchdog? http://www.xess.com/blog/esp8266-reflash/

Comment: Yes I used 0.9 of expressif. The latest one.  Initally it was 115200.. I changed it to 9600.

Comment: @NccWarp9 hey Yes I used 0.9 of expressif. The latest one. Initally it was 115200.. I changed it to 9600

Comment: Im sorry but there is nothing else. I do wonder why you use AT commands  from code.

Comment: @NccWarp9 i wonder is there any other way to communicate ?

Comment: Sure there are, Many. Currently Im testing out MQTT for ESP and it works perfectly. Also you have WebSockets and so on. You can put your own telnet on it, webserver, or program another arduino over the wifi.

Comment: @NccWarp9 I checked for mqtt, etc earlier but i thought its just build upon at library, i will try flashing it again. Really thankyou. 

the mqtt firmware didn't work well in past. I will try again. 

I just want to communicate arduino with ESP8266, any how.

Comment: If you wish only to communicate they I would suggest looking at ESP-Link. I find it one of the most impressive and useful pieces of code out there for ESP

Comment: @NccWarp9 I will give it a try & update you, really thankyou.